# rails 2.3.4 / problem with query string parameters in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, search, get

i work on an old Rails 2.3.4 App.
When i invoke an action of an "baz" controller with an GET param like
www.foo.com/baz/search?search_string=Hello
i get the expected result but i looks like rails is caching the result.

Invoking the action with an new param like
www.foo.com/baz/search?search_string=World
returns the old result.

I did some debugging an realized that this behaviour only occurs in "production env" when
"config.cache_classes" is "true"

Any ideas?
THX!

Comment: Could it be browser caching? If you have wget or curl, try comparing the results of "curl www.foo.com/baz/search?search_string=Hello" and "curl www.foo.com/baz/search?search_string=World"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

config.cache_classes = true in production.rb wouldn't cache any results. It basically means that it wouldn't reload Rails classes in the Production Environment and have them cached,( this is why  the production environment is faster than development )

are you doing some page caching or any other kind of caching in that controller, It would be great if you could post your controller code here.

Comment: Hello Rishav, thanx for the hint. The controller was ok. But i made an error in my custom serach method in my model.